# Tensorflow 2.3. How to change the batch for each epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I would like to train with a different custom image augmentation during each epoch in the training.

- The wrong solution would be to save the augmented images, and run the training on the saved images. Because if you try to loads hundreds of thousands of images for the training, you will get a memory error.
- The right solution will have to use augmentation during the fit routine.

Can you please indicate me how to do it, pointing out a working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't create many images, and you won't get a memory error. While iterating through the dataset, it will apply random transformations to the image, without "creating" new images that will be saved in memory. So just do it normally:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

[train_set_raw] = tfds.load('cats_vs_dogs', split=['train[:100]'],  as_supervised=True)


def augment(tensor):
    tensor = tf.cast(x=tensor, dtype=tf.float32)
    tensor = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(images=tensor)
    tensor = tf.image.resize(images=tensor, size=(96, 96))
    tensor = tf.divide(x=tensor, y=tf.constant(255.))
    tensor = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image=tensor)
    tensor = tf.image.random_brightness(image=tensor, max_delta=2e-1)
    tensor = tf.image.random_crop(value=tensor, size=(64, 64, 1))
    return tensor


train_set_raw = train_set_raw.shuffle(128).map(lambda x, y: (augment(x), y)).batch(16)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow((next(iter(train_set_raw))[0][0][..., 0].numpy()*255).astype(int))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, I will start from your code. BTW, I drive a manual W204 220cdi . Hopefully, I will drive a C63 someday ;).

Comment: The code works me me, however when I load png's from a directory by using:
dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(dir,label_mode=None,batch_size=32)
the mapped function expects 
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 4 and 3 for '{{node random_crop/GreaterEqual}} = GreaterEqual[T=DT_INT32](random_crop/Shape, random_crop/size)' with input shapes: [4], [3].
The same issue is reported in the last post here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40541

Comment: The problems is with the method tf.image.random_crop

Comment: I have just opened it as a separate question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65196460/how-to-random-crop-an-unlabeled-tensorflow-dataset-valueerror-dimensions-must